# Woocommerce CSS changes not applying to site

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I tried to change some design things in my wordpress page in **css/woocommerce.css**.
When I inspect the element I want to hide, chrome says that the class is in that file, but when I change the mentioned class it does not change anything in the frontend, not on the website and not in the chrome inspector.
I cleared all my caches and if I change other CSS files the changes apply just as they should. Just not on woocommerce.css....

Any ideas?

Code of woocommerce.css:

```
.blockUI.blockOverlay {
        position: relative;
        display: none !important;
    }
    .blockUI.blockOverlay:before,
    .loader:before {
        /*height: 1em;
        width: 1em;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -.5em;
        margin-top: -.5em;*/
        display: none !important; 
        /*content: "";
        animation: spin 1s ease-in-out infinite;
        background: url(https://www.afreenuts.com/wp-content/uploads/nuss50.gif) center center;
        background-size: cover;
        line-height: 1;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 2em;
        color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);*/
    }
    .woocommerce .blockUI.blockOverlay:before, .woocommerce .loader:before, .woocommerce-page .blockUI.blockOverlay:before, .woocommerce-page .loader:before {
        display: none !important;
    }
```

Code on Google inspector:

[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAx6W.jpg)
As you can see the display:none; on admin.css applies, but my change son woocommerce.css don't.

Comment: to improve the chances for getting an answer to your problem you should provide code samples.  There is not enough detail in the question as is to understand what problems you might be running into.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the advice. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

**You best not editing things that way, as soon as you update the plugin you'll loose all your changes...**

There isn't much to go on with what you've written but i you need to be editing your theme to override Woocommerce styles, not from within the plugin itself (Im guessing this based on the CSS location you've provided).

I'm also assuming you've 'gotten as far as choosing a theme that suits your needs, that's fine but to make styling changes beyond whats possible in Customizer you need to create a child theme. Here is the info you need [Woocommerce Child theme documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/set-up-and-use-a-child-theme/) and the [Wordpress documentation here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) and finally this is the info for [making the changes to woocommerce](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)

If your just getting started try using the [Woocommerce theme Storefront](https://woocommerce.com/storefront/) which is free and specifically built for Woocommerce and there is plenty of support online for this theme.

I hope this info helps, if you need more advice then you need to include more information, full locations of the files your referring to and any code that's involved. Youll get a much better response this way :)

Comment: I know that, but thanks. The thing is , I still don't get why the changes are not applied properly on specialy this file - makes no sense at all.

Comment: ok so what is the full path to the css file your editing? so i can understand how your doing this and from the chrome inspector have you tried right clicking the element and under the copy menu select "CSS Path"?

Comment: Hi, yeah I tried 'CSS path' it's exactly the same path as the one I go on with on the FTP - that's the strange thing.

Comment: if your not going to paste any code or locations here then no one can help

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else experiencing this problem: Check that your Hosting Company isn't automatically caching your website.

For instance: GoDaddy's Managed Wordpress automatically cache's WordPress sites to make them faster for users.

Thankfully they make clearing your cache quick and easy. Follow the instructions here: https://www.godaddy.com/help/clear-your-cache-12444

This is what my very similar problem ended up being.